# MongoDB SailsJS: Prevent Model.create() if it has undeclared attributes

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

Is there a way to prevent an attribute to store, when if the attribute is not required in api/models/YourModel?

For example, let's say I used MongoDB, and I have this Master model:

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    name:{type:'string',required:true},
    code:{type:'string',required:true},
    description:{type:'string'}
  }
};
```

and I try to .create with this code:

```
Master.create({name:'Test Code',code:'TEST_CODE'}).exec(function cb(err,created){
  console.log('strored');
});
```

Database: Mongo

```
{
    name:"Test Code",
    name:"TEST_CODE",
    description:""
}
```

I want to prevent description key in object.

```
{
    name:"Test Code",
    name:"TEST_CODE"
}
```

I need this output in database

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can avoid saving a value, but you could save a `null`-value by changing your attributes:

```
attributes: {
  name:{type:'string', required:true},
  code:{type:'string', required:true},
  description:{type:'string', allowNull:true}
}
```